# Fetch API return 401 using bearer token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm new in React.
I was experimenting Fetch API in my Full-Stack project, right below i put my fetch code

```
const bearerToken = "Bearer " + token

const fetchDataGet = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/corso/getcorsi-da?id_ca=1", {
            headers: {
                "method": "GET",
                "Authorization": bearerToken,
                "redirect": "follow"
            }
        })
        return response.json()
    }
```

I don't see where is the problem in the Authorization. if I use this type of assignment it returns 401

i managed to reduce the problem using Postman, triyng to put the same url but there i get what I expect, so I tried to fix the header, what I found is that if I use a string with the bearer token (just copy and paste the generated string) it returns 200, but, if I use the assignment above what I get is 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: Can you give the data that you see in headers?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check if your token is not undefined?
Also noted that the structure of the request is not correct as method and  redirect is not a part of the header.[Follow this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to learn the correct use. The correct structure should be

```
const bearerToken = "Bearer " + token;

const fetchDataGet = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/corso/getcorsi-da?id_ca=1", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": bearerToken
        }
    });
    return response.json();
}
```

Comment: i have already tried your structure. I tried it again but nothing is changed, i always get 401

Comment: The code you've provided is not really enough detailed as I cannot see where the token is defined. However, suggest to inspect your request in network tab and looking at the headers to see what is being attached.

Comment: I checked the headers attached and what I see in the Authorization header is Bearer "eyJh......" but if I look in the postman console the Authorization value is "Bearer eyJh...". Is it possible that the problem is that the word Bearer is not in the double quotes?

Comment: I decided to use template literals, so ``Bearer ${token}``, something changed. What i get is a preflight type response with 200 but even another response with 401